# DNN 5.02 and IE 11

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

Since IE 11 is out our Website www.kose.ch as well as a few others we created have no navigation anymore, only in compatibility mode.

We don’t know if it’s an issue of DNN or of our Skin (Dr. Nuke).

Can someone give us a tip how to solve this problem?

Comment: What's DNN?  Have you tried any debugging on your own?

Comment: I think he is referring to DotNetnuke, a .NET CMS system. @user3166896 i think you will have a faster answer on the dnn-forums, or if its really broken, consider reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Likely a known issue with older versions of DNN and old skins. I would recommend you upgrade to a new version of DNN, or see if the developer who created the skin has a new release out (I would doubt it).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot update the skin at the moment you can do the following as a temporary FIX. NOTE THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED FOR LONG TERM.

Edit Default.aspx to have the following META tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Depending on DNN version you may need to edit the default IE=Edge value.